# Complexity of OBDD isomorphism (representing same function after permutation of variables)?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

According to wikipedia [Ordered Binary Decision Diagarams (OBDD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) are a data structure that is used to represent a Boolean function.

OBDD is a DAG with two sinks $0,1$.

The size of the BDD is number of vertices in the DAG.

Let $B_1,B_2$ be OBDDs of sizes $s_1,s_2$ and representing
the boolean functions $f_1,f_2$. $B_1,B_2$ are on equal number
of variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and $y_1,\ldots y_n$.

OBDD isomorphism $B_1 \to B_2$ is a permutation $\pi$ of the $x_i$s,
such that for all $x_i$, $f_1(x_i)=f_2(\pi(x_i))$.

> What is the complexity of deciding OBDD isomorphism?

This is closely related to circuit isomorphism, but
OBDDs are very nice representation of boolean functions
compared to other representations.